# Add exposed filter for user roles

Tags: 7, views, ubercart

In Ubercart, the uc_order view (admin/structure/views/view/uc_orders) uses exposed filters for status and order ID.

I can add another filter, for example username, email and so on by clicking on *Add filter criteria* and selecting the criteria (user:username, user:email).

I need to add a filter to filter orders by the roles assigned to customers. There is no option such as user:roles in the filter criteria list to select.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

By configuring the **Access**: section on the **Page settings**, we can manage Page: Access restrictions.

Choose the **Roles**  and assign the required user role.

Comment: No, I don't want to restrict access to this page. I want to allow the administrator to filter orders by the selected customer roles. I need to add an exposed filter.

Comment: Using hooks you can alter the views.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to open "advanced" section, add new "relationship" marked as "order:customer". After this new options in "add filter" will be available. So click at "add filter" and select "user:role" and set it as "exposed to users".